# If a sentence does not fit in a single line, break into a new line where indicated

Tags: html, css

Our landing in mobile looks ugly because the sentences are cut into two lines but only the last word jumps into the next line. Let me explain it better with an example. Let's say in **desktop** the sentences is:

> Hello this is my beautiful website. You are welcome!

On **mobile**, the text is broken at the last word, which looks ugly:

> Hello this is my beautiful website. You are
>
> welcome!

However, **only in mobile**, I'm trying to achieve something like:

> Hello this is my beautiful website.
>
> You are welcome!

So far, the best idea I have is showing a text block in mobile and another different block text in the rest of devices doing something like:

```
@media(max-width:480) {
.hide_on_mobile {
   display: none;
}

@media(min-width:480) {
.hide_on_non_mobile {
   display: none;
}
```

But this is not a very elegant solution in my opinion... Is there a better one?

Comment: well if you are using the css word-break properly and it keeps happening, i can recommend you to add a little padding to make the words break wherever you want (only on mobile) instead of toggling between two text containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a conditional line break instead :

```css
@media(min-width:480px) {
  .mobile_only {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello this is my beautiful website. <br class="mobile_only"/>You are welcome!
</div>
```

Comment: I have receive so many answers!!! I have chosen this one because I think it's the easier to read :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use br tag and break whatever you want and you can use media query to avoid it in pc or mobile . example given below

```css
@media (min-width: 375px) {
  h2 br {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
  <h2>Hello this is my beautiful website. <br> You are welcome!</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is probably the most common. But I guess you could also do something like:

HTML:

```
<div id='paras'>
    <p>This is sentence one.</p>
    <p>This is sentence two.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#paras p { display: inline-block; }
@media(max-width:480) {
    #paras p { display: block; }
}
```

This isn't super elegant either, but does at least mean that the paragraphs will sit next to one another on desktop, then stack on mobile.

The drawback is that, on desktop, they'll *never* stack, even if you want them to. So you'll need manual breaks:

HTML:

```
<div id='paras'>
    <p>This is sentence one.</p>
    <p>This is sentence two.</p>
    <p class='break'>This is sentence one A.</p>
    <p>This is sentence two B.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.break::before { content: '.'; visibility: hidden; display: block; }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29kchn56/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Put the block in span

```
<span class="blockOnMobile">Hello this is my beautiful website.</span> <span class="blockOnMobile">You are welcome!</span>

@media(max-width:480) {
.blockOnMobile {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .text span{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Hello this is my beautiful website. <span>You are welcome!<span><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A potential css solution is to lower the width of your text section so that it drops the last sentence onto the next line when the width is less than 480px.

If you wanted to delve into javascript, you could create an if statement where if the width of the body is less than 480px, the innerHTML of your div equals = "Line One
Line Two";.

Hope that helps! Happy to explain further if you require.